# PHP - add/remove carriage returns to a base 64 encoded string

Tags: php, string, encoding, textarea, base64

I have a verrrrrrrry long base64 encoded string which is displayed in a textarea. The problem is that this string doesn't have any spaces or carriage returns so it gets displayed on one line with a ugly horizontal scroll bar.

Can I add somehow carriage returns manually after base64_encode() and before output to the textarea, then remove these CR's after retrieving this string from the textarea (before decoding)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`chunk_split`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) to split your string into chunks of a specific length, and then rejoin those chunks with the character or string you want:

```
$str = base64_encode($whatever);
echo '<textarea name="textarea">'
     . chunk_split($str, 30, "\n") // put a newline every 30 characters
     . '</textarea>';
```

As [`base64_decode`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) ignores whitespace, you don't need to do anything special once you retrieve the textarea value.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly. White space is ignored:

```
<?php

echo base64_encode('Lorem Ipsump'); // TG9yZW0gSXBzdW1w

echo base64_decode('TG9 yZW0gS      XBz dW1w'); // Lorem Ipsump

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
base64_decode(wordwrap(base64_encode('very ... long'), 80, "\n", true)) == 'very ... long'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could simply use the HTML attribute [`wrap`](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmltextarea.php) to do it in pure HTML and bypass any PHP implementation...

```
<textarea name="foo" wrap="soft"><?php echo $encodedString; ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the PHP function [wordwrap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).